# WPF - How could I get a scrollviewer control from my XAML file in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I need to get a specific ScrollViewer control from an XAML file in C#, so that I can try to implement a drag-and-scroll system where when an item is dragged near the edge it will scroll accordingly. But I need access to all the methods to do this, yet I cannot find any info as to how to get the specific scrollviewer from the XAML.

I need access to it from a separate .cs file in which most of the project's converters and functions are located. Not sure bout the downvotes tho seeing as I did lots of research on it. Here is some of the code:

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="timelineScrollerRight" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" PreviewMouseWheel="TimelineScrollerRightMouseWheel">
```

That is the ScrollViewer tag that I want to access. I want to change the LineRight/LineLeft attributes of the ScrollViewer in a `MouseMove` event triggered by another control within the ScrollViewer.

The C# code is bare right now, the event is empty, I want to be able to declare a variable to allow me to change the ScrollViewer attributes so that when the MouseMove event is called, the ScrollViewer is scrolled and so on. The ScrollViewer is located in a file named TimelineAnimationView.xaml and the event happens in the code-behind, TimelineAnimationView.xaml.cs. But I would also like to access it from a separate .cs file if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you access it using `x:Name`:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scoller"/>
```

If you are doing this with loose XAML such as in a `UserControl` or `Window`, you just access it as a private instance variable `scroller` in your code-behind.

If you are doing this with a ScrollViewer in a template, then you have to use `GetTemplateChild` (in `OnApplyTemplate`) to find the child type with the relevant name:

```
scroller = GetTemplateChild("scroller");
```

Comment: What would be the syntax to access a scrollviewer with `x:Name` in C# code-behind?

Comment: You just use `scroller` as you would any field. So for instance, `scroller.GetHashCode()` would return the hash code, and `scroller.ActualWidth` returns the current width of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how to initially get the xName scroller into a variable in the code-behind. How so I initialize it?

Comment: If the control has a name attribute there should already be an automatically created reference to in a variable at the class level..

Comment: @AliEgseem I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. The `x:Name` goes in the XAML, and then it initializes a hidden field with the name `scroller` after the XAML is loaded via `InitializeComponent()`. Is that not working for you?

Comment: I was under the impression I could just do something like ScrollViewer.getByName(xname) or something like that. Is there no way to get a scrollviewer by xname from the code-behind? I am new to WPF and XAML so I don't know.

Comment: Try reloading the answer - I made an edit and added more code. What kind of class are you doing this in? Is it a Control? Or a UserControl? A Window? Something else?

Comment: I'm doing this in a separate .cs file in which I have converters for bindings and such. I'm not sure if it is a class similar to the ones you mentioned, but I just want to access elements from the XAML from my .cs file. I'm used to PHP and such where you can get things by element names, is there anything similar?

Comment: Without seeing the XAML and c# code you are working with, I'm not sure.

Comment: I added the ScrollViewer tag itself in the OP, but the C# code is empty aside from the event header.

Comment: WPF normally works by having XAML inside of a class (the `<Window x:Class="...` or `<UserControl x:Class="`. Is your XAML in one of those?

Comment: The XAML is in `<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Animation.TimelineAnimationView"`. In the code-behind .cs file, the namespace is MyProject.Animation with public partial class TimelineAnimationView.

Comment: Ok, so normally that XAML code would be in a `TimelineAnimationView.xaml`, with a `TimelineAnimationView.xaml.cs` file beneath it (assuming you are using Visual Studio). If you go into `TimelineAnimationView.xaml.cs` you should just be able to use the field `timelineScrollerRight` in your code, at least in non-static methods.

Comment: @NextInLine thank you! That is weird compared to other frameworks but I guess it is useful. Any way I could get access to timelineScrollerRight in files not near TimelineAnimationView?

Comment: You can make a public property in `TimelineAnimationView` C# code that returns the value of the `timelineScrollerRight ` field. You then have to have access to the TimelineAnimationView object to access that property.